# Launching app from NFC tag reading

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc

I've read and read, but I can't understand what do I need to do exactly to make the application launch when I touch a NFC tag (a list pops with TagWriter and on{X})

I've added this to my applications Main Activity (in Manifest)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

And I also write and read the tag with `application/com.pgsideris.aeglea` NDEF Data within the application

I would welcome some detail, as most other posts don't offer much and the links they provide have confused me somewhat.

Comment: And? Your activity doesn't start? What does logcat report?

Comment: No that's not the problem. I want to start the application when it's not running. It rather starts with on{x} and not with my app. How do I do it to launch my app with the swipe of an NFC tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason for those applications to pop-up is you are filtering for mimetype "text/plain" and if you wrote an NFC-tag with that mimetype all applications including your own application will respond to the tag.

If you are correctly writing the NFC-tag, perhaps post some code to verify that, you should filter for mimetype "application/com.pgsideris.aeglea" this results in the following filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/com.pgsideris.aeglea" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The code is too long and I have perplexed it too much, so I can't post some specific block(it sounds weird, but I wonder myself how I did it)

Comment: So that's how you declare which app you want to launch! Thanks. I get some errors, but it's not something I can't work out.

Answer (score 2):

Does your app need to read the tag, or do you only need to start it? If the latter, Android provides a custom NDEF rectord in which you can specify the exact package (app) to start. Cf,  Android Application Record (AAR):  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createApplicationRecord(java.lang.String)

If you want to read the tag, and your app is not in the foreground you will get a selection dialog if other apps on the device have registered to handle the same tag, NFC technology, etc. You cannot change this, only make sure your app gets priority if it is already in the foreground by using foreground dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the permission to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"></uses-permission>
```

Depending on the type of tag, you may need to filter the tag. For example, to filter for tags that contain urls pointing to yourserver, you would put this in your intent-filter:

```
           <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="yourserver.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/"/>
```

Comment: The NFC permission is not needed at all if the only thing you want to do is receive an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent.